search the values in a range of rows in a column thru a table array
I'd like to find a formula/function in excel to help me out to search for a set of values in a range of rows in a column thru a table array. The output I'm expecting is to have the column with the same values highlighted or have the top cell of the column with the same values highlighted. Any other indication out of the column/top cell of the column found might work too. For instance the values in B3,B4,B5,B6 must be searched thru the array C3 to M6. Any other column that matches the values from B3 to B6 must be highlighted.
I tried VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP, INDEX, MATCH, CONDITIONAL FORMATTING with no luck.
